# Can't Get It Right: Adding An Event Listener to Elements From getElementsByClassName

Tags: javascript, dom

Please tell me what's wrong with the code below:

```
            for(var i = 0; i < image.length; i++) {
                image[i].appendChild(overlay);

                image[i].addEventListener("mouseover", function() {
                    this.firstChild.style.backgroundColor = "rgba(0, 0, 0, 0)";
                    this.style.backgroundSize = "340px 240px";
                    this.style.WebkitTransition = "all 0.5s";
                    this.style.transition = "all 0.5s";
                }, false);  

                image[i].addEventListener("mouseout",function() {
                    this.firstChild.style.backgroundColor = "rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.7)";
                    this.style.backgroundSize = "300px 200px";
                    this.style.WebkitTransition = "all 0.5s";
                    this.style.transition = "all 0.5s";
                }, false);
            }
```

What this does is loop through the image array of elements which I got from using getElementsByClassName() function.

```
var image = document.getElementsByClassName(ClassName);
```

The error I get from the browser's console is this:

[image]

If I have missed out anything you need to know, please let me know. Or if you have any suggestion on how to make this code better, bring it on.

Note: No jQuery.

Comment: How can an image possibly have a first child?

Comment: Is the `firstChild` a text node, perhaps?

Comment: It's the name of a class - not an actual image.

Comment: In a case `image` doesn't contain image elements (which can't contain children) you're moving `overlay` from an element to an other. You've to create a new element to append to each `image[i]`.

Comment: The firstChild is an empty div whose transparency and background color changes.

Comment: You are right in that. I created a layout element which is then appended to the image element.

Comment: Yes, but you've only one element, you're just changing the parent of it. After the loop it is appended to the last element in `image` collection.

Comment: Oh, so I will need to create a copy every time I am appending to the image element?

Comment: Yep, using for example [`cloneNode`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Node/cloneNode) method. If the cloned  element have an `id`, make sure the `id`s will be unique after cloning too.

Comment: Give it as an answer. You were right.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You've only one `overlay` element, you're just changing the parent of it. After the loop it is appended to the last element in the `image` collection.

To fix this you can create a copy of the `overlay` every time you append it to a new parent, something like this:

```
image[i].appendChild(overlay.cloneNode(true));
```

Just in case the cloned element had an `id`, you've to create a new `id` for each clone, something like this:

```
var clone = overlay.cloneNode(true);
clone.id = clone.id + i; // Adds i to the end of the id, use date or some else unique string instead, if you're running the loop multiple times
image[i].appendChild(clone);
```